# merge multiple overlapping polygons of table into one and remove the one already merged

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have multiple polygons which I want to combine if they are overlapping

```
id;geom
1;"POLYGON((2 1,4 1,4 4,2 4,2 1))"
2;"POLYGON((3 3,5 3,5 5,3 5,3 3))"
3;"POLYGON((1 0,3 0,3 2,1 2,1 0))"
```

Here all 1 is overlapping with other two (1,2) and (1,3) so the end result should be one big poylgon so I expect only 1 row in the table now.

I am somewhere in the middle of the query where I get overlapped polygon but it is merged but and combined all together and also the already merged one is not deleted.

```
 SELECT a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id, ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom), st_astext(ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom)) as new_geom
  FROM public.testpostgis a
  JOIN public.testpostgis b ON a.geom && b.geom AND ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)
 WHERE a.id <> b.id
```

this prints the output like this

```
a_id;b_id;overlap;new_geometry
1;2;t;"POLYGON((4 3,4 1,2 1,2 4,3 4,3 5,5 5,5 3,4 3))"
1;3;t;"POLYGON((2 2,2 4,4 4,4 1,3 1,3 0,1 0,1 2,2 2))"
2;1;t;"POLYGON((3 4,3 5,5 5,5 3,4 3,4 1,2 1,2 4,3 4))"
3;1;t;"POLYGON((3 1,3 0,1 0,1 2,2 2,2 4,4 4,4 1,3 1))"
```

In the end the table should contain no overlapping polygons so here it should only be 1 row with merged geometry.

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be aggregated as follows:

```
select a_id, count(1) as union_cnt, st_astext(st_union(new_geom))
from (
  SELECT a.id as a_id, ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom),
      ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom) as new_geom
  FROM gis1 a
  JOIN gis1 b ON a.geom && b.geom AND ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)
  WHERE a.id <> b.id
) x
group by a_id
order by count(1) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The result for your example is:

```
1|2|POLYGON((2 2,2 4,3 4,3 5,5 5,5 3,4 3,4 1,3 1,3 0,1 0,1 2,2 2))
```

HTH

Comment: It should delete already merged ones so the end result should be only 1 row.

Comment: Actually I found this solution. SELECT st_astext((ST_DUMP(ST_UNION(ST_SNAPTOGRID(geom,0.0000000)))).geom) as geom
FROM public.testpostgis

Comment: If you asume or able to ensure all your data _always_ have overlapped region then, yes, this can be the solution. But you mention "I have multiple polygons which I want to combine if they are overlapping"